# Transfer data from Samsung smartphone without unlocking

Tags: samsung, broken-screen, data-transfer

I have Samsung A3. I accidentally broke display. Now I can't unlock the phone. I know I can change the display. But I want to know whether there is a way to transfer data to PC without unlocking phone. I generally use data cable for transfer.

Comment: See related Q&A under the tags [tag:broken-screen] and [tag:locked-out].

Comment: And the corresponding tag-wikis, e.g. [broken-screen](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/broken-screen/info) – as they often contain a summary, first-aid, and more (@Firelord better link those next time ;)

Answer (score 0):

One way in which you can do this is, if you have data stored on a Micro SD card, you can get an adapter and connect it to the PC.